# Populating an Email with multiple addresses

Tags: javascript, html, forms, email

I have an HTML table that's populate based upon information in a database, and want to have, at the bottom of the table, a button that, when clicked, opens up an email client (ala an HTML mailto:) and has multiple addresses in the TO: field that are based on certain cells in the table.

I have the HTML for the button.

```
<input type="button" id="emailAll" value="Email All">
```

And I started on this little piece of code to gather the email addresses when the button is clicked:

```
$("emailAll").click(function($){
  var emailCell = 4;
  var length = document.getElementById("orgTable").rows.length;
  var emailArray = [];
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
   emailArray.push(document.getElementById("orgTable").rows[i].cells[emailCell].value);
  }
});
```

However, I'm not really sure where to go from here. 
I've read that it's bad-form(?) to have multiple email addresses in a mailto:, so I'm not really sure where I should go from here? Also, I'm not even sure if the code as I currently have it will work (for example, I'm pretty sure the "emailAll" part is wrong?), so any correction would be appreciated! =]

Also, sorry if this has been asked before.

Thanks!

**EDIT**
So here's a few more details, because the answer I have right now unfortunately isn't working.

This is being used on a wordpress site, and the code needs to be called from inside a post. When I try to use the code I have, a bunch of HTML tags are added into the source, such as `</p>`, etc. this leads me to believe that even in the non-visual mode for the WordPress editor, that the formatting is still being applied. How would I work around this?

Also consider that I can't put the script in the  of my HTML.

**EDIT 2**

Okay, so here's the code for the table. I'm using it in a Formidable Pro (a Wordpress Form Plug-in), so the [number] correspond to a field.

```
<div class = "fullWidth">
    <table id = "orgTbl">
    <thead id = "orgheader">
        <tr>
            <th class="orgheadercell" colspan = "5">[get-team]</th> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th> ... </th> 
            <th> ... </th> 
            <th> ... </th> 
            <th> ... </th> 
            <th> Email Address </th> 
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="orgbody">
        <tr class = "orgbodyrow">
           <td class="orgbodycell">[249]</td>
           <td class="orgbodycell">[250]</td>
           <td class="orgbodycell">[322]</td>
           <td class="orgbodycell">[336]</td>
           <td class="orgbodycell">[264]</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
        <tr>
        <td class="orgheadercell" colspan = "5">
            <form id="getEmails" action="" method="GET">
                <input type="submit" id = "emailAll" value="Email All" />
            </form>
            <script src = "/wp-includes/js/create-email.js" type="text/javascript">
            </script>
        </td> 
        </tr>
     </table>
</div>
```

So, what you're looking at is a work-in-progress, still have to clean it up a bit before it's ready to go. But anyways, as I was saying, the [number] field is replaced with the actual value held in that, and the content between the `<tbody>` and `</tbody>` is repeated for each entry in my database.

Also, I realize my script had "orgTable" listed, but I changed it to the correct "orgTbl". Additionally, as I thought `value` would give me the value in the cell, and it apparently is for drop down menus, I changed that to `innerHTML`. Still no luck though.

Answer (score 1):

Put your button inside a form like this:

```
 <form action="" method="GET">
        <input type="submit" value="Email All" />
    </form>
```

For javascript, onload, put this:

```
$("emailAll").click(function($){
  var emailCell = 4;
  var length = document.getElementById("orgTable").rows.length;
  var emailArray = [];
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
   emailArray.push(document.getElementById("orgTable").rows[i].cells[emailCell].value);
  }

  // once you got your array of email properly from your table, try this
   $('form').get(0).setAttribute('action', "mailto:"+emailArray.toString()); 

});
```

**Edit**: I forgot to add **mailto:** to make the action act like mailto link in href attribute.

Comment: So what should I do with the string then once I click the button? Because from what I understand the form having the "GET" method is only going to paste that into the URL, and (I'm kind of guessing here) display a string of the array when what I want is it to act similar to a "mailto:" link in HTML?

Comment: I edited my post, I forgot to add mailto: to the action attribute. In this case it will act just a normal mailto: link, it will open you email program a put as recipient the list selected with emailArray, separated by comma. Try and you're going to see. I tried it and it works for me.

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't work for me. I'm going to update my original question with some more details so I can get to the bottom of this!

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Wordpress, but try to print your array  **emailArray**. Are you getting your list of emails from your HTML table without a problem? Because if there's nothing inside, the code will not work. Can you post the HTML code of your table where you store the list of email?

Comment: I'll update the original question with the table code and an explanation of how it works.